# \includegraphics not working with multicol package

Tags: multicol, sharelatex, includegraphics

When using the `multicol` package, images do not show up. It works when I don't use this package. How can I include images with two columns. I use the following:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{image.png}
\end{figure}

\end{multicols}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a warning:

```
Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside `multicols' environment!.
```

Thus, floats like `figure` are not allowed, but `\includegraphics` works fine.

The star forms `figure*` or `table*` can be used inside environment `multicol`, but the float elements are put outside.